# Migrating iTunes library to Linux system?

Tags: linux, itunes, migration

I am planning to migrate from Mac OS X to Linux in the near future. Is there an equivalent to iTunes for Linux and how would I migrate to it? I have mainly music in my current iTunes library, iPod syncing from Linux would be ideal, too.

Comment: If you've got an iPod Touch or iPhone, you are out of luck.

Comment: Fortunately I don't! But I do have an iPod Classic which I hope to sync with.

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Amarok](http://amarok.kde.org/) supports iPod syncing, but I'm not sure about library migration from iTunes.